# Linux device driver stepper motor

Tags: device-driver

hi i am new to Device driver, i am writing code to driver a stepper motor using ioctl...my code goes this way

```
            while(is_transmit_empty() ==0);
            outb(0x99, SERIAL_PORT_BASE);
            printk("data sent\n");
            mdelay(500);
            while(is_transmit_empty() ==0);
            outb(0xCC, SERIAL_PORT_BASE);
            printk("data sent\n");
            mdelay(500);
            while(is_transmit_empty() ==0);
            outb(0x66, SERIAL_PORT_BASE);
            printk("data sent\n");
            mdelay(500);
            while(is_transmit_empty() ==0);
            outb(0x33, SERIAL_PORT_BASE);
            printk("data sent\n");
            mdelay(500);
```

and my

## define CLOCKWISE _IO(MAGIC_NO, 0 )...

with this code my stepper motor rotates only one step even though its in a loop for 50 for rotating 360-deg......

tell me where am i going wrong with my code .....

Comment: i got the solution .....there's no problem with this code...its working fine ..its due the bipolar nature of the stepper motor, the energizing of the coils cannot be assured with their direction of rotation.....

Comment: You should post your solution/answer as an answer. Click the "Answer Your Question" button at the bottom of the page. Then accept your own answer. Otherwise this question will forever show up as unanswered...